# Is this an appropriate use of a GLM? and if so how do I predict a specific outcome?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, proportion

I am hoping that someone might be able to provide me with some assistance. A colleague of mine was told to use a GLM of family binomial and a logit link function for some of the data they submitted in a paper. They are looking at the effects of temperature regimes on the proportion of seeds that germinated of an endangered plant species. Given the status of the plant the samples sizes are small.

Three populations of plants were sampled, each time with 10 seeds being germinated under various temperature conditions (note: the 30/20 is indicative of a 30 to 20 degree cycing regime). My data in R looks like this:

```
> data
   Temperature Population_Year numGerm
1            5      Pop_C_2009    0.00
2            5      Pop_C_2010    0.00
3           10      Pop_C_2009    0.00
4           10      Pop_C_2010    0.00
5           15      Pop_C_2009    4.50
6           15      Pop_C_2010    3.50
7           20      Pop_C_2009    9.00
8           20      Pop_C_2010    9.00
9           20      Pop_S_2009    7.84
10          25      Pop_C_2009    9.00
11          25      Pop_C_2010    9.00
12          25      Pop_S_2009    9.00
13          30      Pop_C_2009    9.00
14          30      Pop_C_2010    9.00
15          30      Pop_S_2009    8.00
16          35      Pop_C_2009    7.84
17          35      Pop_C_2010    9.00
18          35      Pop_S_2009    7.84
19          40      Pop_C_2009    1.84
20          40      Pop_C_2010    3.50
21        3020      Pop_C_2009    9.00
22        3020      Pop_C_2010    9.00
23        3020      Pop_S_2009    9.00
```

With numGerm being the number of seeds that germinated. I then developed the following model:

```
GM<-cbind(numGerm, numNoGerm = 10-numGerm)
GM
Model1<- glm(GM ~ Temperature,family=binomial(logit), data=data)
summary(Model1)
```

The following output was generated:

```
Call:
glm(formula = GM ~ Temperature, family = binomial(logit), data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-4.174  -1.491   1.328   2.218   2.227  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) 0.3225745  0.1446465   2.230  0.02574 * 
Temperature 0.0006383  0.0002129   2.998  0.00272 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 142.16  on 22  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 128.48  on 21  degrees of freedom
AIC: 172.93

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

So now this tells me that temperature is positively (and significantly) influencing the proportion of seeds germinated. However, I would now like to predict the temperature at which all seeds might germinate or alternatively the probability of all seeds germinating at a given temperature (I hope my wording of this is adequate). This is where I get stuck as I am not entirely sure how to go about this. I have done the following, but I may be confusing things and cannot determine what the qualitative value is of the output I am getting.

```
predictor<-data.frame(Temperature=c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,3020))
predict(Model1,predictor,type = "response")

   1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9 
0.5807288 0.5815057 0.5822821 0.5830581 0.5838338 0.5846090 0.5853838 0.5861581 0.9046656
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

**updated with new results, adding in a covariate for cycling:**

```
> data
   Temperature cycling Population_Year numGerm
1            5       0      Pop_C_2009    0.00
2            5       0      Pop_C_2010    0.00
3           10       0      Pop_C_2009    0.00
4           10       0      Pop_C_2010    0.00
5           15       0      Pop_C_2009    4.50
6           15       0      Pop_C_2010    3.50
7           20       0      Pop_C_2009    9.00
8           20       0      Pop_C_2010    9.00
9           20       0      Pop_S_2009    7.84
10          25       0      Pop_C_2009    9.00
11          25       0      Pop_C_2010    9.00
12          25       0      Pop_S_2009    9.00
13          30       0      Pop_C_2009    9.00
14          30       0      Pop_C_2010    9.00
15          30       0      Pop_S_2009    8.00
16          35       0      Pop_C_2009    7.84
17          35       0      Pop_C_2010    9.00
18          35       0      Pop_S_2009    7.84
19          40       0      Pop_C_2009    1.84
20          40       0      Pop_C_2010    3.50
21          25       1      Pop_C_2009    9.00
22          25       1      Pop_C_2010    9.00
23          25       1      Pop_S_2009    9.00

Model1<- glm(GM ~ Temperature+cycling,family=binomial(logit), data=data)
summary(Model1)
```

output is now:

```
Call:
glm(formula = GM ~ Temperature + cycling, family = binomial(logit), 
    data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-4.758  -1.399   0.000   1.548   2.563  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.57717    0.38555  -4.091 4.30e-05 ***
Temperature  0.08397    0.01577   5.324 1.02e-07 ***
cycling      1.67510    0.62981   2.660  0.00782 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 142.164  on 22  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  95.445  on 20  degrees of freedom
AIC: 139.43

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

**Update 2:Addition of population as a covariate**

```
Model1<- glm(GM ~ Temperature+cycling+Population_Year,family=binomial(logit), data=data)
summary(Model1)

Call:
glm(formula = GM ~ Temperature + cycling + Population_Year, family = binomial(logit), 
    data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-4.1807  -1.3694   0.3702   1.3162   3.0337  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -2.23022    0.51507  -4.330 1.49e-05 ***
Temperature      0.07985    0.01578   5.059 4.21e-07 ***
cycling          1.64228    0.63302   2.594  0.00948 ** 
Population_Year  0.41742    0.20929   1.994  0.04611 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 142.164  on 22  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  91.354  on 19  degrees of freedom
AIC: 136.84

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Comment: Can we trust 3020$^\circ$C (presumably Celsius is being used here) as a temperature? Wouldn't it incinerate the seeds? This is not just a detail as the temperature dependency depends on it.

Comment: Hi Nick, the 30/20 indicates a 20 to 30 degree cycling regime, I will add this to the question.

Comment: If you entered 3020 into the analysis, results need to be redone. Perhaps use 25 and add a covariate for cycling, except that you aren't exactly drowning in degrees of freedom.

Comment: @NickCox, Excuse my ignorance, but how would I go about adding in a covariate for the cycling as you mentioned?

Comment: Just add another variale with 0 for not cycling, 1 for cycling

Comment: @mdewey, perfect, thanks! I will do this and update the question to address my other issues.

Comment: If you think population and year could make a difference, you need covariates for them too.

Comment: @NickCox, I had considered that but I am not very interested in the effect of population, as this functions more as a source of replication...

Comment: Being interested in it and whether it makes a difference are two different matters. If I were a reviewer of your paper/examiner of your dissertation/whatever, I would look askance at lumping together different kinds of seeds without checking for a difference.

Comment: @NickCox, fair point! I was just progressing on the basis of what my colleague was interested in but I will add this in and update. Thank you :)

Comment: @NickCox, given the updated results, it is just as well that I added this based on your reccomendation

Comment: How can you have `7.84` out of `10` seeds germinating?

Comment: Also, thinking logically about the termperature, I wouldn't be too sure about a linear relationship between the germination chance and the temp. After all, what happens at >40 degrees. Does the chance just keep going up?

Comment: Nothing linear here except on logit scale.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam, in terms of the linear relationship, biologically speaking exposure to temperatures greater than 40 will significantly diminish the capacity of the seeds to germinate..As for your other comment, you are perfectly correct in saying you cannot have 7.84 seeds germinating. I had the original percentage germination data and am awaiting the actual numbers of seeds in each trial. However, this will take a while to get so I have made the assumption of 10 seeds. The exercise I am going through is to develop the appropriate code and the ability to accurately interpret the results.

Comment: @NickCox Sure, but I hope you understand what I was going at.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam I can't be sure of what you were getting at, except that on very broad grounds I expect that (a) there is an optimum temperature for germination and (b) some thresholds which stop it altogether. (a) might be better modelled with a quadratic.

Comment: That was my point. :) Sorry for the poor wording.